# Get parent category name from subcategory - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to find the parent category name when within a subcategory page on WooCommerce, i.e. I have 4 main categories.

**Parent1**

- Sub 1
- Sub 2
- Sub 3 etc

**Parent2**

- Sub 1
- Sub 2
- Sub 3 etc

and so on.

If I am on the list page for Sub2 which is a child of Parent1 I want to know the name of the Parent1 category.

Answer (score 1):

Try using wordpress `get_ancestors` function:

`get_ancestors( $product_cat_id, 'product_cat' );`

It will return an

> Array of ancestors from lowest to highest in the hierarchy

Hope it helps!